# Customize <url-pattern> to link a Form to a FormAction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

First, I am a newbie in Java/J2EE development. So, please be indulgent with my leak of vocabulary (but feel free to correct me ;)

- Here is my first problem :

I built a first form (named form1) in a .jsp page :

```
<form name="form1" action="formaction1.do" method="get">
```

I redirect the result of my form to a FormAction1 java class :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.myproject.FormAction1</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>FormAction1</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FormAction1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my FormAction1 java class :

```
public class FormAction1 extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("formaction1.jsp").forward(request, response);     
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is working fine.

Now, I'd like to create another form, named form2, and link it to FormAction2.
However, FormAction1 receives every .do request !

I tried to customize my `<url-pattern>` by writing :

```
<url-pattern>formaction1.do</url-pattern>
```

I guess it would've been too easy :D
Tomcat doesn't like it : I get a 404 error on every page of my project.

So, do you have any solution ?

- Just a bonus question :

What's the point to use a class like FormAction1, rewrite doGet method, while I can just write :

```
<form name="form1" action="anotherFile.jsp" method="get">
```

and recover infos with a request.getParameter() in anotherFile.jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't url-pattern requires a match starting from the beginning, in that case

```
<url-pattern>/formaction1.do</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Seriously... so easy ? shame on me :D Any idea for my bonus question ?

Comment: Writing a jsp is just another form of servlet, by writing your own servlet you might write more efficient code than a precompiled jsp->java source->class file. But that's really nitpicking. One of the advantage would be a better separation of concerns, the action take care of the data then redirect to the views, in that case you would not care about the user refreshing the resulting page.